# Live Preview in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

The MediaWiki [manual](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aLive_preview) states the following:

> **Enabling live preview**
>
> Live preview is on or off depending on
>   the `$wgLivePreview` variable of
>   `LocalSettings.php`. To activate it you
>   must also enable it on a per-user
>   basis in the "editing" tab of you user
>   preferences page.

However, when I go to the article describing the variable [`$wgLivePreview`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgLivePreview), it says that this variable was deprecated in **1.15.x**.

Is there any alternative and relatively similar way of enabling Live Preview in the current version (**1.16.5**) of Mediawiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the variable (along with live preview itself) was removed in [r59446](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aCode/MediaWiki/59446); the feature was then restored in [r62173](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aCode/MediaWiki/62173) and turned completely always-on in [r65390](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aCode/MediaWiki/65390).

[It looks like 1.16 was branched from around r62818](http://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki?view=revision&revision=62819), so you can set `$wgLivePreview` to make the option visible in the user preferences. Or apply r65390 to your local installation, or install the 1.17 beta release instead of 1.16.